# Change the order of custom field for Woocommerce variable products in admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I followed this tutorial for adding custom fields into WooCommerce variations.

http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/

Everything worked great...

However the method for inserting the field into the dashboard (product edit) area doesn't mention **how to change the order of the field as seen in the dashboard**.
.
[image]

```
// Add Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
// Save Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field', true )
        )
    );

}

function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    // Text Field
    $text_field = $_POST['_text_field'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `woocommerce_variation_options_pricing` will put it after the price (it may need some CSS). It's the closest hook I found after price input.
- Using `woocommerce_variation_options` will put it before price input
- Following called hook in template is `woocommerce_variation_options_inventory`

In those cases, you can check yourself what is possible by:

- finding the related Woocommerce template (in plugin directory)
- studying the code to find `do_action` (or `apply_filter` for variables) to see "where and when you can do/update stuff". In your case `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-variation-admin.php:159`
- sometimes your are lucky (merciful devs), sometimes less :)